# Why CSS is not working correctly on different page sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have my toolbar:

```
    <header className='toolbar'>
        <nav className='toolbar_navigation'>
            ///hamburger:
            <SideDrawer drawerClicked = {props.drawerClicked} />
            ///LOGO
            <div className='toolbar_logo'>MYCOOKIES</div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And here is my styling:

```
.toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E4E7ED;
    background-color: white;
}

.toolbar_navigation {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    padding-left: 18px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.toolbar_logo{
    color:#bfa290;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    font-weight: 510;
    margin-right: 115px;
    font-size: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

So, everything seems fine(i hope), but when i open it on phone it shows different things.
Example on iphone 6: http://prntscr.com/sujtsb
Example on iphone 5: http://prntscr.com/suju09
Why this is happening? And can someone help me?) I would be really thankfull!

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about aspect ratios.
The iPhone 5 is at least 45px less in width than the iPhone 6. This means that you have to use something like `vw` instead of `px` for those margins to make sure they look similar on different mobiles.
Read up on css units and media queries for more help.

Comment: Thanks, but what is better to use ```vw``` or ```%```?

Comment: For example, change that `115px` to `20vw` and you should see what I mean.

Comment: % makes use of the width of the parent element but vw makes use of the width of the screen.

Comment: That means that if the width of the parent element was smaller than the total width of the screen, `80%` would be be 8/10 of the parent's width but `80vw` would be 8/10 of the width of the whole screen.

Comment: No feedback. Did this help you?
If it did, set it as the answer.